# Is there any way from an IOS app to see the browsing behaviour of a user

Tags: ios

I would like to develop an app that, given the right permission, can in any way get information of the browsing habits of a user, and in particular one or more of the following things:

- Browsing History
- Bookmarks
- Searches

Is it possibile in iOS?

Comment: I don't think its possible except when u make your own browser app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the iOS eco system it is impossible to fetch browsing history. Applications are sandboxed and isolated from one another. It's part of the security model, provided by Apple.

But for the jailbreaken iPhone it is possible.You can find history plist file at this directory :`/var/mobile/Media/Safari/`